# Table of content in Newsletter

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it valid to have

> Table of Contents

in Corporate Newsletter?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Writers.SE.  Could you clarify what you mean by "valid"?  Are you looking for style guides that support this?  Are you asking how common it is?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your publication contains enough identifiable discrete units of content, then it is valid (and desirable) to provide a Table of Contents to aid readers.

On the other hand, if your document template includes a place-holder for a ToC but you are struggling to find what to put in it, then it may be time to change the template. If the Table of Contents is not serving a useful purpose for the end user, then you do not need it (regardless of what the market leaders do).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The key question is, How many entries would such a Table of Contents have, and how big is the newsletter? If the answer is, "one, because each issue of the newsletter is pretty much just one article", then clearly there's little point. But if the answer is "twenty", then it makes sense. Likewise if the newsletter is a single sheet of paper, then readers can probably see everything that's in it at a glance anyway. If it's ten pages, a TOC makes more sense.

I used to edit a newsletter for a small non-profit organization. Our typical issue was six pages -- three sheets of paper -- with maybe ten articles or so per issue. So I would put a box in the corner of the front page with a small TOC. I didn't want to use up a whole page for a small TOC like that, but it was worth having.